# Prize for the announcer badge?

Tags: discussion

I couldn't help but notice over at [music.se](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/stack-improvement-drive-musical-practice-and-performance?cb=1), one suggestion was to give out modest prizes when people gained the announcer badge, encouraging more people to share links to questions. Is this something that would be possible to implement here? Only 4 of these badges have been awarded so far, and more of an incentive to share questions may well provide a bit of a push.

Slightly cheeky suggestion I know, but if you don't ask...!

Comment: Not to be a Debbie Downer but: two of the four people who won the Announcer badge are SE employees.

Answer (score 6):

I think this sounds like a great idea to bring more traffic to the site. We could alternatively make it into a raffle - everyone who gets an announcer badge gets 1 entry per badge, booster gets 2, and publicist gets 3 or 4, and then at the end of the contest (maybe a couple weeks or a month) we pick a few names and send them some SE swag (we won't get our own until we graduate) and/or a gift certificate for some outdoors store (REI or similar).

I've made sure the SE team has seen this, so hopefully we'll get a response from them at some point.

Comment: Any update from the SE team on this one?

Comment: This is pretty good! A simple raffle-style promotion. We'd need to flesh it out a bit but this looks like a great start!